# Statistical Power Analysis for reight skewed data sets

Tags: nonparametric, statistical-power

I have price Data for a set of items for various time steps as i collect this data regularly. The data is very large (over 250000 items usualy per group per point in time) and not normaly dstributed but slightly right skwed.
Sometimes the item count drops for certain timepoints and groiups and i want to calculate if i can still make safe assumptions about the meassures of central tendency of the underling distributions.

I was considdering using statsistical power analysis. but i am not sure if this works in this case, and i am not sure which test i actually need to perform.

Furthermore, inbetween these points in time there can be shifts of the measures of central tendency, as for example a certain group will increase in price as a whole.

So how is a meaningfull Poeranalysis done in this case with skewed datasets?

In the end i want to have a trigger if i have enough datapoints to draw colclusions from the sample means (i.e. the mean price has droped x% etc)

Edit:

- I collect Price data for a certain Product Groups within a certain Market
- I aim to describe general market trends by comparing means/medians between consequitive points in time (usually the data is collected every month)
- Sometimes we do not have the possibility to collect a large amount of data and hence we only have a fraction of the data points as in the month before
- The market can of course move and as a result the mean Price (for example) changes. As a Result i am not really comparing Data that originates from the same distribution as they come from different points i time.
- The data is very right skewed (much more low than high Prices)
- I want to neglect this fact and have an estimated how much my statistical power has droped when i go from 1000000 datapoints to maybe 100 datapoints
- In reality we have much more data for many product groups and want to filter points were our statistical Power is to low to conduct any meaningfull analysis if a mean Price (or example) has changed between to consequitive points in time.

Thank you in andvance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you have 250K points per group per point in time then you probably don't need to do power analysis

Comment: The problem ist that sometimes this count drops to values blow 5000 a certain points in time.

Comment: I’m concerned about the time series nature of the data. Could you please describe in detail what you want to do and what data you have?

Comment: @DaveI added some context

Comment: TBH, I think the answer to the original question is to log transform the prices, because prices are often log-Normally distributed, but there are other problems to be addressed before this analysis would be a good idea.

Comment: @Eoin I reality i am not using the prices directly but a related quantity. But i would be very interested to know what problems i would need to address. I would really appreciated you insight! Thank you in advance